# Does Humidity Have an Effect on WiFi Packet Loss?

Tags: wireless-networking

The speed of my home wifi network varies significantly from day today (I'm talking 50% or more) and I'm trying to get to the bottom of it.  It's mostly consistent in locations where there is no physical obstruction between the router and the host.  The inconsistency occurs only when there are walls in between.

It tends to perform better on dry days which is what makes me consider humidity as a possible culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Humidity can affect Wi-Fi speeds, but not enough for the average user to notice.  So, relax and don't worry about humidity.
You need to find out what channel(s) your router is configured for and make sure that your neighbors routers are not on the same channel.  If they are, once their activities increase, you will get interference which will result in slow to poor performance for you.  You may want to change your channel to a less congested channel.

Comment: Thanks. I’ll try to relax. Dealing with slow internet is very stressful for me. :-)